# Try the keywords "lock" in IIS ,but it's no effect,only one processid

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

```
public class OrderJob : IJob
{
    private static readonly object LockObj = new object();

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        //判断是否可以获取到排它锁，如果获取不到，则跳出等待
        var canEnter = Monitor.TryEnter(LockObj);
        if (!canEnter) return;
        lock (LockObj)
        {
            Log.Debug($"{Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id}:{Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode()}:{this.GetType().Name} : entered:{DateTime.Now:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ffffff}");

            Log.Debug($"{Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id}:{Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode()}:{this.GetType().Name} exited:{DateTime.Now:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ffffff}");
        }
    }
}
```

I lock a static object in my code ,but  in the IIS, the log is like below:

记录时间：2017-04-27 10:40:00 
日志级别：DEBUG 
出错路径：Himall.Service.Job.FightGroupJob.Execute
错误描述：1249476:88:FightGroupJob entered:2017-04-27 10:40:00 055398 
出错方法：Execute

记录时间：2017-04-27 10:40:00 
日志级别：DEBUG 
出错路径：Himall.Service.Job.RefundJob.Execute
错误描述：1249476:89:RefundJob : entered:2017-04-27 10:40:00 056375 
出错方法：Execute

记录时间：2017-04-27 10:40:00 
日志级别：DEBUG 
出错路径：Himall.Service.Job.RefundJob.Execute
错误描述：1249476:69:RefundJob : entered:2017-04-27 10:40:00 058328 
出错方法：Execute

记录时间：2017-04-27 10:40:00 
日志级别：DEBUG 
出错路径：Himall.Service.Job.FightGroupJob.Execute
错误描述：1249476:35:FightGroupJob entered:2017-04-27 10:40:00 059305 
出错方法：Execute

记录时间：2017-04-27 10:40:00 
日志级别：DEBUG 
出错路径：Himall.Service.Job.FightGroupJob.Execute
错误描述：1249476:149:FightGroupJob entered:2017-04-27 10:40:00 060281 
出错方法：Execute

记录时间：2017-04-27 10:40:00 
日志级别：DEBUG 
出错路径：Himall.Service.Job.RefundJob.Execute
错误描述：1249476:148:RefundJob : entered:2017-04-27 10:40:00 061258 
出错方法：Execute

记录时间：2017-04-27 10:40:00 
日志级别：DEBUG 
出错路径：Himall.Service.Job.FightGroupJob.Execute
错误描述：1249476:6:FightGroupJob entered:2017-04-27 10:40:00 063211 
出错方法：Execute

记录时间：2017-04-27 10:40:00 
日志级别：DEBUG 
出错路径：Himall.Service.Job.RefundJob.Execute
错误描述：1249476:7:RefundJob : entered:2017-04-27 10:40:00 067118 
出错方法：Execute

记录时间：2017-04-27 10:40:00 
日志级别：DEBUG 
出错路径：Himall.Service.Job.FightGroupJob.Execute
错误描述：1249476:149:FightGroupJob entered:2017-04-27 10:40:00 091533 
出错方法：Execute

记录时间：2017-04-27 10:40:00 
日志级别：DEBUG 
出错路径：Himall.Service.Job.FightGroupJob.Execute
错误描述：1249476:88:FightGroupJob entered:2017-04-27 10:40:00 123760 
出错方法：Execute

记录时间：2017-04-27 10:40:00 
日志级别：DEBUG 
出错路径：Himall.Service.Job.FightGroupJob.Execute
错误描述：1249476:35:FightGroupJob entered:2017-04-27 10:40:00 128643 
出错方法：Execute

记录时间：2017-04-27 10:40:00 
日志级别：DEBUG 
出错路径：Himall.Service.Job.FightGroupJob.Execute
错误描述：1249476:6:FightGroupJob entered:2017-04-27 10:40:00 147199 
出错方法：Execute

记录时间：2017-04-27 10:40:01 
日志级别：DEBUG 
出错路径：Himall.Service.Job.RefundJob.Execute
错误描述：1249476:89:RefundJob exited:2017-04-27 10:40:01 099384 
出错方法：Execute

记录时间：2017-04-27 10:40:01 
日志级别：DEBUG 
出错路径：Himall.Service.Job.RefundJob.Execute
错误描述：1249476:69:RefundJob exited:2017-04-27 10:40:01 123799 
出错方法：Execute

记录时间：2017-04-27 10:40:01 
日志级别：DEBUG 
出错路径：Himall.Service.Job.RefundJob.Execute
错误描述：1249476:148:RefundJob exited:2017-04-27 10:40:01 127705 
出错方法：Execute

记录时间：2017-04-27 10:40:01 
日志级别：DEBUG 
出错路径：Himall.Service.Job.RefundJob.Execute
错误描述：1249476:7:RefundJob exited:2017-04-27 10:40:01 406036 
出错方法：Execute

Comment: Seems that the process ID is `1249476` shown in all log texts, what do you want to achieve then? Also can you translate some Chinese text to English (especially some simplified characters I'm not familiar with)?

Comment: pay attention on the log info,its not in pair,entered & exited ,the lock statement seem to be no effect.  the Chinese is only some descripe,you can ignore it.

Comment: Could you please expand your logging to:

    $"{Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id}:{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName}:{Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode()}:

and post the result?

Comment: Do the CurrentDomain may effect the lock?And how to prevent this?

Comment: That's why I'm asking. Monitors should not normally synchronize across domains and IIS might use different domains for different requests. "Note that you can synchronize on an object in multiple application domains if the object used for the lock derives from MarshalByRefObject." - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor(v=vs.110).aspx#Overview